# How can I create a script that will verify dns server are synced?

Tags: dns, dig

I would like to create a script that verifies if all the DNS servers that are responsible for resolving a website are synced.

For example, when I execute `dig ns walla.co.il +short` I get the following:

`a18-65.akam.net. a11-64.akam.net. a9-64.akam.net. a1-39.akam.net. 
ns1.bezeqint.net. ns3.bezeqint.net. ns2.bezeqint.net. a22-66.akam.net. a26-67.akam.net.`

All those DNS servers are responsible for resolving that hostname (walla.co.il)

Then, I execute the following: `dig soa walla.com @a18-65.akam.net. +short`
The output will be `ns1.bezeqint.net. postmaster.bezeqint.net. 2016102612 28800 7200 604800 300`
When I will execute the same using the second hostname (a11-64.akam.net) I will get the same number that shows that they are synced (2016102612) >>> `ns1.bezeqint.net. postmaster.bezeqint.net. 2016102612 28800 7200 604800 300`

How can I create a script that will verify that all the name 9 servers in the list above are synced, without checking that manually?

Thanks :)

Comment: `for ns in $(dig ns walla.co.il +short); do dig soa walla.co.il @$ns +short | cut -f 3 -d ' '; done | sort -u | wc -l`, the result should be 1 if they are in sync